# How to include parameters in plot title in comsol?

Tags: finite-element, software, comsol

I have a comsol model. I want to draw a few plots for different values of a global parameter called `plot_z`, e.g. if `plot_z` can have 5 different values I want to draw 5 different plots, one for each value. In each plot I need to write the value of `plot_z` parameter in the plot title. I have typed many expressions such as `plot_z`, `$plot_z`, `%plot_z%`, etc. in the plot title text box, but unfortunately none of them worked.

Is it even possible to have the value of a global parameter in plot title?

Comment: Hi Mehrdad, and welcome to scicomp!  Have you tried asking this question on the official COMSOL forum?  http://www.comsol.com/community/

Comment: Hi @Paul, well, I am from Iran and as a result of american sanctions against Iran they have suspended my account!

Comment: I suspect the answer depends on the version of COMSOL you are working with (since the interaction with Matlab - where such a thing would be easy - changed over time).

Comment: I have comsol 4.2. so, Christian, you mean that I need to use matlab for doing this? matlab livelink?

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario I would suggest to use matlab livelink. I'm not aware of how to include these global parameters in the comsol figures without loading it into MATLAB. If you do opt to do it in MATLAB, you could use the following code.:

`plot(x,y)`

`title(['Your Title',num2str(plot_z)])`

You may also need to change your code to address the different parameters, maybe using a for loop.